# HTTP 502 on all App Engine Requests

Tags: google-app-engine, gcloud, health-monitoring, google-cloud-platform

Using the new GAE [Split Health Checks](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/nodejs/configuring-your-app-with-app-yaml#updated_health_checks), all my GAE requests now return **502** errors. Even after removing Split Health Checks from my app and redeploying, I still get exclusively **502's**.

Steps taken, toggle off health checks:

```
gcloud beta app update --split-health-checks
```

gcloud SDK: **v168.0.0**

Error Message:

```
<html><head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8">
<title>502 Server Error</title>
</head>
<body text=#000000 bgcolor=#ffffff>
<h1>Error: Server Error</h1>
<h2>The server encountered a temporary error and could not complete your request.<p>Please try again in 30 seconds.</h2>
<h2></h2>
</body></html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. There are errors in Split Health Checks that can fail irrecoverably. These can't be fixed in your app code.
2. The gcloud SDK does not allow disabling of Split Health Checks as
       written. The documentation is erroneous in its instructions to
       disable this feature

The proper way to disable Split Health Checks is to use the undocumented `--no-split-health-checks` flag like so:

```
gcloud beta app update --no-split-health-checks
```

Then redeploy your app.

Comment: link to [--no-split-health-checks](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/nodejs/configuring-your-app-with-app-yaml#enabling_updated_health_checks) flag docs. For legacy health checks, disable using "enable_health_check: False"

Comment: Thanks @Kenworth. The linked page has no reference to that flag, and the docs for `v168.0.0` for `gcloud beta app update` lack any reference. Let's hope the docs are fixed soon.

Comment: Thanks @Joseph. I filed a documentation bug about the issue so that `--no-split-health-checks` is visible to the public.